# what is the meaning of this in Mule 3 #[payload.?status == 'completed']

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

In mule 4 the below statement can be used to check weather element is present or not. it returns true or false

```
payload.key?
```

can some one please explain what is the meaning of using question mark in the below statement mule 3.

```
#[payload.?status == 'completed']
```

how can we achive same in mule 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a "Null Safe" way of fetching values from a payload. You can refer the official document here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/mel-cheat-sheet#chained-elements

> In this example, if a field named address is null, the expression
> throws a NullPointerException.
>
> ```
> #[payload.address.zipcode]
> ```
>
> To make this same expression null safe, use the .? operator.
>
> ```
> #[payload.address.?zipcode]
> ```
>
> Using this operator avoids a NullPointerException if address is an empty value, instead it returns
> null.

In Mule 4 this is changed, and it is always null safe when extracting data. i.e. `payload.address.zipcode` will return null if address or payload null

Comment: how to achive this in muel 4?

Comment: Mule 4 is null safe by default. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: @kushmagonna As aled mentioned, it is the default behavior with mule 4. do you mean that you want to make the expression fail if the field is null in mule 4?

Comment: thank you I checked it is the we will get by default a null value